# Order of connecting points in paraview under table to structured grids

Tags: paraview

I'm a beginner in Paraview. I have a question about displaying CSV file in Paraview. If my data file looked like this

```
x coord, y coord, z coord, scalar
0, 0, 0, 1 
1, 0, 0, 2
0, 1, 0, 3
1, 1, 0, 4
0, 0, 1, 5
1, 0, 1, 6
0, 1, 1, 7
1, 1, 1, 8
```

It will create a cubic grid. But if I switch the order of points like

```
x coord, y coord, z coord, scalar
0, 0, 0, 1 
1, 0, 0, 2
1, 0, 1, 6
0, 1, 0, 3
1, 1, 1, 8
1, 1, 0, 4
0, 0, 1, 5
0, 1, 1, 7
```

It will give me a really messy connected wireframe. I want to know what's the order of connection? How does Paraview form those grids?

Comment: When I open this csv-file in paraview the data is shown in a spreadsheet. How do you get paraview to display it as a wireframe?

Comment: What I did is to apply Table to Structuredgrid filter and then create object in render view.

Answer (score 0):

In ParaView (and indeed in the underlying VTK library it uses), structured grid points are ordered such that the index of the x dimension varies fastest, the index of the y dimension varies second-fastest, and the index of the z dimension varies slowest. Hence, your first example gives the expected result while the second example does not.

Comment: thank you very much. Is there any resourse where I could have find this information?